# Disable android system volume overlay

Tags: android, overlay, volume

Is there a way to disable/override the volume overlay/toast ? (its not actually a real toast)

I want to replace it, I already wrote a system Overlay which acts like the original, plus there are more sliders.

Now I just want to disable the original *(image below)* so it is not displayed.

[image]

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the following function to diable the volume buttons:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
boolean result;
 switch( event.getKeyCode() ) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        result = true;
        break;
     default:
        result= super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        break;
 }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: I have to mention, a broadcast starts my service, I just use windowManager to add and remove Views, therefore I get touch-events (so my SeekBars actually work, -> they won't if I were using custom toast) but the activity in the background is not disturbed/paused. 
That's why I can't use an activity, and your code only works in an activity if I am not mistaken. :/

Is there any way to override these using manifest.xml ?